# What is & operator in php

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I was searching for a password generator tutorial, which I found one but somethings got me a little confused...

```
if ($strength & 2) {
$vowels .= "AEIOU";
}
```

What exactly is this operator? I know && equals "and" but just one &?

Comment: Was really annoying that half of my question got removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in most programming languages, `&` is the bitwise and operator. `x & 2` tests whether the second (least significant) bit of `x` is set (`2` is `10` in binary).

Comment: Yes, except in VB.Net (and earlier VB's if I remember correctly), in which case it's the string concatenation operator.

Comment: So how in this way is $strength being tested? Cause its testing 1, 2, 4, and 8.. What do the 1 2 4 and 8 mean?

Comment: Which you wouldnt know that cause some dude removed half my damn question cause its "possibly" a duplicate..

Comment: @David they are powers of two, which are 0001, 0010, 0100, and 1000 in binary, respectively.

Comment: @Zach Thanks bud.. Still dont understand it but ill just echo or print_r every step of the function till i do..

Comment: @David: from my cursory glance at the code that was edited out, it looks like the person who wrote that code is using $strength as a bitwise flag variable.

Comment: @Zach yea the code that was there wouldve helped quite a few people answer the follow up questions i had. Was really annoying that it was removed. Thanks again

Comment: Testing against 1, 2, 4, and 8 means asking whether the first, second, third, and fourth bit of `$strength` are set.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH Ok so 8 would mean that hte 4th bit is set, and 4 would be third and so on! OK! I get it now. Thanks!
Btw do bits go higher than 4? Like if i did 16 wouldnt that mean that the 8th bit would be set?

Comment: `x & 16` would test for the fifth bit (`16 = 2 ^ 4 = 10000` in binary). Of course, higher bits can be tested accordingly. Usually, integers have a size of 32 bit (signed).

Answer (score 2):

That is called a bitwise operator. [Learn more.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

Answer (score 0):

It's the [bitwise and](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Answer (score 0):

`&` is the [bitwise AND operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). It sets bits that are in both numbers that are tested.

Example: `6 & 4`

```
6 ->     1 1 0
4 ->     1 0 0

6 & 4 -> 1 0 0 -> 4
6 & 4 = 4
```

Example: `13 & 10`

```
13 ->     1 1 0 1
10 ->     1 0 1 0

13 & 9 -> 1 0 0 0 -> 8
13 & 9 = 8
```